# What is the best way to convert a JSON object to be inserted in SQL Server

Tags: mule-studio

I'm new to Mule Studio and  am running a query against a MySQL database, converting the object to JSON and then mapping it to the columns in a SQL Server database that I am pushing the data to.

However, I am not sure about the best way to handle the mapped JSON. Can I insert the JSON directly into SQL Server or does it need to be converted to an object first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems revolving around JSON and database storage.

First you need to decode JSON data (in php there is `json_decode`), for mule studio [look at this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JSON+Module+Reference) documentation. It looks like you should use `@JsonAutoDetect`.
As for storage on database, the data type of a variable should match that with the field.